# How does Spring bean Handle concurrency

Tags: spring, thread-safety, javabeans

My web application uses Spring IOC. So all my spring beans will be singletons by default. In case if two requests try to access two different methods of a single class (for example `MySpringBean` is a class which has two methods `searchRecord` and `insertRecord`) at the same time, both the requests will access the same spring bean concurrently.

How does the same spring bean be available to both the clients at the same time or is it going to be concurrency problem when both the requests will try to access two different methods but through the same spring bean. And since spring bean is a singleton so new instance can not be formed. In this case how is this going to work?

Answer (score 16):

You must first understand when concurrency can cause problems. If your Spring bean is stateless (it doesn't have any fields, all fields are `final` or all of them are assigned only once), multiple threads can safely use the same bean, or even the same method.

## See also:

- [thread safe, stateless design using Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189907)
- [spring mvc declaring all beans singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147314)

Comment: Yes. But how do we best deal with concurrency when our bean has a field?

Answer (score 7):

If the bean is a singleton, then Spring will give you the same instance in any thread.  It's up to you to make that bean thread-safe.  Since it's a singleton, you'd be best off making that class stateless.

Answer (score 6):

As others have already suggested, Spring is going to provide the same instance to all the threads in case of "singleton" beans.

What you need to understand is that threads do all the work in a system by executing the code while objects provide state and behavior (code). So it is indeed possible for multiple threads (requests in your case), to be concurrently running same methods in a singleton bean. You can either make such beans stateless as Tomasz suggested or otherwise make them "thread-safe".

Comment: I don't want to block the next thread when it tries to write into a bean member field. Do you have a recommended technique to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Java singleton and spring singleton are different. Spring singleton scope will be available within context.

Java singleton scope will be in JVM class loader. Hence concurrent request possible only through spring contexts

Answer (score 0):

In Spring, every request will be created in a separate thread. for example, they can be called "searchRecord" thread and "insertRecord" thread.
both of them will find the same object in the heap, but each thread creates its own stack of execution.